# How many sides of an odd-sided equiangular polygon must be proven equal to conclude that it is regular?

Tags: geometry, angle, polygons

If we know that all angles are equal in a polygon with an odd number of sides, how many sides need to be shown to be equal to claim that the polygon is regular?

For example, if we know that a triangle is equiangular, we can directly claim that it is regular. However, we cannot do the same for a pentagon, since there are pentagons which are equiangular but not equilateral.

So, does it depend on the number of sides?

Comment: $n-2$. it comes down to when $n$ is odd, the tangent vectors for any two edges of an equiangular $n$-gon is linear indepedent.

Comment: Think of the polygon as solid, and you can always remove a sliver by making a cut parallel to one of the edges, thereby shortening the two adjacent edges.